# Hibernate save three entities in another one

Tags: java, hibernate

Small question that has bugging me for a long time.

I have three entities: A, B and C.
I want to save all three entities in entity D.
Entities A, B and C have a OneToMany relationship with entity D.
Entitiy D has a ManyToOne relationship with A, B and C.

Parents in this relationship are A, B and C. This means that if A, B or C gets deleted, entity D containing one of the tree entities (A, B or C) also has to be deleted.

**Example**

In a Parent-Child relationship I already know how a child is being saved.
Parent(P) and Child (C)

```
c.setParent(P);
p.setChild(c);
p.save();
```

**My situation**

In my situation Parents are A, B and C. Child is D.

```
a.setChild(D);
b.setChild(D);
c.setChild(D);
d.setParents(A, B, C);
a.save();
b.save();
c.save();
```

Saving this 3 times (on the side of the Parents) gets me 3 records in the Database and i obviously want one. 
How can I fix this? 
If i understand it correctly, you need to save on the parent side when creating a child.

### Edit

Entities A, B and C already exist when creating entity D.

Comment: Better to share your Entity class

Comment: You're not saving any relationship; you're saving object a, b and c.

Comment: @MauricePerry I will update my question, made a mistake.

Comment: Shouldn't you have B and C already in database after saving A? When you save A, you save D, but D can't exist without B and C, hence this two should be saved before saving D.

Comment: @EganWolf I made some mistakes in my question, will update it